# $\mathbb{Z} [x] $as union of three proper subring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

We know that the union of two subrings is a subring if and only if either of the subring is contained in the other. so there's no Ring $R$ as 
union of two proper subring. Now let R be finte ring  then we can write R as union of three proper subring if $|R|=4,8,16$. For infinite ring( for example $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ ) Can we write $\mathbb{Z} [x] $as union of three proper subring ?

Comment: Are your (sub)rings unital?

Comment: @DanielFischer . Yes.

Comment: Then lisyarus's answer is probably the most elegant possible.

Answer (score 4):

*I assume that we are talking about unital subrings.*

In fact, $\mathbb Z [X]$ cannot be a union of any number of proper subrings.

Suppose $\mathbb Z [X] = \bigcup R_i$, all $R_i$ being proper subrings. Then, $X \in \bigcup R_i$ means that $X \in R_i$ for at least one $i$. But $X$ generates the whole $\mathbb Z [X]$  as a ring, thus $\mathbb Z [X] \subset R_i$, which contradicts $R_i$ being a proper subring.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see how many subrings one needs to write $R[x_1,...,x_n]$ as a union of proper subrings